# Change css display when userAgent if user is on iPhone & window.navigator.standalone == true

Tags: iphone, html, css, user-agent, getelementbyid

I'd like to build a webAPP and displaying different content, when

1. user open the webAPP via their safari browser
   or
2. when they open the webAPP through a webclip from home screen

The detection works - I check it with document.write - but the CSS display property is not changing. **What am I doing wrong?**

Thanks upfront!

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1) {
    if (window.navigator.standalone == true) {
        // document.write('<p>homescreen<\/p>');
        document.getElementById("homescreen").style.display = 'block';
    }else{
        // document.write('<p>safari<\/p>');
        document.getElementById("safari").style.display = 'block';
    }
}else{
        // document.write('<p>no iOS<\/p>');
        document.getElementById("ios").style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="homescreen" style="display:none;">
you opened it from the homescreen
</div>

<div id="safari" style="display:none;">
you opened it from safari
</div>


<div id="ios" style="display:none;">
you have no iOS
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<script>` is evaluated before the DOM is loaded, thus `document.getElementById("xx")` returns `undefined`. Check your javascript error console, there's probably an error like: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null".

1. Either move the `<script>` block to the end of your body
2. Better yet, use jQuery and something like, see http://api.jquery.com/ready/

   ```
   $(function() {
     if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1) {
       if (window.navigator.standalone) {
         $('#homescreen').show();          
       }else{
         $('#safari').show();
       }
     }else{
       $("#ios").show();
     }
   });
   ```

Or what might be an even better and more flexible alternative is to append classes to the `<body>` element, then you can easily show/hide anything using CSS.

```
$(function() {
   if (window.navigator.standalone) {
     $('body').addClass('standalone');
   }
});
```

Then in the CSS all sections can easily be shown/hidden based on these identifiers.

```
.someContent { display: none; }
body.standalone .someContent { display: block; }
```

For the mobile selector (iPhone), you might even avoid the JS userAgent switch (FYI, your `indexOf` wouldn't match iPads or iPod Touches) und better rely on CSS media queries like `@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)` (this one is for an iPhone landscape & portrait).

Comment: Worked for me , I had to use diff font-family for android and iphone, normal web. I added class for each using above It worked. Thanks